# shopping Cart Update Qty onKeyUp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code to update my Cart items Quantity:

```
<div class="cart-col cart-col-qty" data-caption="Quantity">
<div id="item-count-@item.item_id">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartItems[ix].Count,
           new
           {
               @class = "test11 form-control",
               @type = "text",
               @min = "0"
           })
    <a href="#" class="RefreshQuantity tessss btn btn-danger btn-to-danger btn-sm btn-icon" data-id="@item.item_id"
       txt-id="CartItems_@(ix)__Count"><i class="fa fa-2x">+</i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

I am using ajax to make a post request upon clicking the `anchor` element  with this code:

```
  $(".RefreshQuantity").click(function () {
// Get the id from the link
var recordToUpdate = $(this).attr("data-id");
var countToUpdate = $("#" + $(this).attr("txt-id")).val();
if (recordToUpdate != '') {
    // Perform the ajax post
    $.post("/ShoppingCart/UpdateCartCount", { "id": recordToUpdate, "cartCount": countToUpdate },
        function (data) {
            // Successful requests get here
            // Update the page elements
            if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
            }
            location.reload();                
        });
}
});
```

I want to remove the click function on the `anchor` and use the input's onKeyUp event to make the ajax request with the cartItem id and the quantity without page refresh. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of .click

```
    $("#YourElement").on('keyup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //This will avoid post form
        if (e.keyCode === 13) { //This evaluates enter key
            //Your logic
        }
    });
```

Comment: look at my code snippet again and tell me how your answer would work

Comment: Change this: $(".RefreshQuantity").click(function () to this: $("#YourElement").on('keyup', function (e), basically...